# Terms aggregation on an inner object and retrieving bucket metadata

Tags: elasticsearch

We index the following products:

```
{
    "id": "1",
    "name": "the-name",
    "categories": [
        {
            "id" : 10,
            "name" : "cat-1"
        },
        {
            "id" : 20,
            "name" : "cat-2"
        }
    ]
}
```

We are doing an aggregation on `categories.id` using :

```
REQUEST:
//...
"aggs": {
    "by_cat": {
        "terms": {
            "field": "categories.id",
            "size": 10
        }
    }
}

---
RESPONSE:
// ...
"by_cat" : {
    "buckets" : [
    {
        "key" : 10,
        "doc_count" : 804
    },
    {
        "key" : 20,
        "doc_count" : 327
    },
```

It works well, however, each bucket contains only the `categories.id` in the `key` field. What we would like is to be able to have the name of the category in the bucket, for example :

```
// ...
      "buckets" : [
        {
          "key" : 10,
          "metadata": {
              "name": "cat-1"
          },
          "doc_count" : 804
        },
        {
          "key" : 20,
          "metadata": {
              "name": "cat-2"
          },
          "doc_count" : 327
        },
```

What is the good way to do that ? We found two to get this information but they both looks "hackish" :

- Using top_hits with size 1 and source limited to categories, it will retrieve one document per bucket containing the information we need. This first solution doesn't look performance-wise and the more aggregation we have, the more bloated is the response.
- Adding a new column id_name which concatenate id and name and doing the term aggregation on it. It looks more like a hack, and may be complicated if many fields.

We also tried by mixing field and script in terms but it doesn't help.

[metadata](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/agg-metadata.html) looked exactly what we wanted but it is global for all the buckets and not dynamic.

Do we have other way to retrieve this information ?